# Download button in yii code

Tags: download, yii

I want the button of download in yii  framework
when i click on that button then new pop up window will open for to ask to open or save ..
plz help me sooon
thank you so much....

I have tried like this but it will open in new window only i cant download...

```
echo "<b>".$data->job_related_file->srvr_name."</b> (".CHtml::link("<b>Download</b>",$downloadLink,array('target'=>'_blank')).")";
```

[image]

When I click on word button then see this image

[image]

Comment: Good quality Image... If I weren't on Linux I'd try and click on that OK button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 
//action in the CONTROLLER

```
function actionDownload($name){
  $filecontent=file_get_contents('path_to_file'.$name);
  header("Content-Type: text/plain");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  echo $filecontent;
  exit;
}
```

//download link in view

```
echo "<b>".
  $data->job_related_file->srvr_name."</b> (".
   CHtml::link("Download","CONTROLLER/download/$filename",
      array('class'=>'donwload_link')
   )
  .")";
```

I haven't tested it though , let me know if this works

Comment: target=_blank means it opens in new window?@sakhunzai

Comment: sorry I ll remove that , you dont need target blank thing  . the popup you are expecting , will be provided by the BROWSER , you don't need it

Comment: actually the HEADERS you are sending from php will do the trick (popup for save as or view)

Comment: yes you will see that popup when you have proper headers sending for each type of file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9681/discussion-between-uk123-and-sakhunzai)